# meaning of The Hen by Lord Dunsany

Tags: symbols, the-hen, lord-dunsany

It's clear that "[The Hen](http://www.flashfictiononline.com/fpublic0044-the-hen-lord-dunsany.html)" by Lord Dunsany is a parable about people who have traveled versus those who are stay-at-homes, but I can't quite put my finger on the complete explanation. Could someone help?

Comment: For those who wonder if this is on-topic (e.g. SFF), see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifty-One_Tales

Comment: I see nothing in *this particular story* that is fantastical other than talking animals.

Comment: Also, for this sort of open-ended analysis, you'd probably be better off asking on [Literature:SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Sadly, yes, this particular story seems to be off-topic (cc @DVK). And the question is too old to migrate to Literature :-(

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Given its age and the fact the OP hasn't been on site in 5+ years, I don't think there would be any harm in simply re-asking it on Lit.

Answer (score 1):

At the time there was a lot of interest in mysticism and how the world is far greater than what we see around us. I must admit I'm not that familiar with Dunsany's work, but Lovecraft is on record as saying Dunsany as an influence on him, and Lovecraft's work is full of ideas about the hidden domains that lie beyond our known world.

So the story is just comparing the mjority of us, the hens, with the mystics and visionaries, the swallows. The majority think the world consists of just what we see and don't believe in anything else. The *enlightened ones* (pardon the cliche!) know that we've explored only a small fraction of the world and great wonders lie beyond.

Answer (score 1):

I took the message to be that there is plenty of wonder in small things, especially to someone who has never seen such things before.  The swallows and the hen each make a journey southward, then return to the farmyard.  The swallows, naturally, go much further, and they see beautiful things:

> And going South they went by glittering fog-banks and saw old islands lifting their heads above them; they saw the slow quests of the wandering ships, and divers seeking pearls, and lands at war, till there came in view the mountains that they sought and the sight of the peaks they knew....

These are impressive sights, but they are normal parts of the swallow's world.  They travel that way every year.

The hen, and the other domesticated animals, have never gone so far.  The South that the hen sees, though she goes a short distance,

> as far as the high road, and saw the great world’s traffic going by, and came to lands where the potato grew, and saw the stubble upon which men live, and at the end of the road had found a garden, and there were roses in it — beautiful roses! — and the gardener himself was there with his braces on,

is more miraculous to the barnyard animals than anything the swallows see, because the hen's sights were truly new *to the hen*.  The road traffic, and the gardens with potatoes and roses made a stronger impression on the hen than what the swallows see, as they pass high over the wide world.  The hen, in turn, passes on her wonder to the other animals, in a way that the swallows, who take their travels for granted, never have.

So, when judging whether something is impressive, important, or beautiful, it matters most of all how new something is.